# Функция preg_match в c++

Tags: php, парсер, c++

Если такая функция в c++ ?

Нужно переписать функцию parser_url с php на c++. Исходный код функции на php:

```
  function parser_url($url) {
    preg_match ("~(.+)?:\/\/([^\/]+)([^\?]*)[\?]?([^\/]*)~", $url, $arr);
    if($arr[4]!==''){$path .= "?".$arr[4];}
    return array ('scheme' => $arr[1], 'host' => $arr[2], 'path' => $arr[3]);
   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `Boost regex`. [Пример пользования с Хабры.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/64226/)
2. Проверьте у себя этот хэдер, может вам и не придется ничего скачивать

   ```
   #include <regex.h>
   ```
3. Есть еще http://pcre.org/. Perl регулярные выражения. PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions.
4. [От Microsoft](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/bd99f343-4ff4-4041-8293-34c054efe749/default.aspx).
5. [От Яндекса](https://github.com/dprokoptsev/pire).
6. Вот еще: [Henry Spencer's Regexp Engine Revisited](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4421/Henry-Spencer-s-Regexp-Engine-Revisited).

Comment: В данном случае наиболее уместный вариант -- pcre.

Comment: спасибо за помощь